# Extract sound file from electronic answering machine

Tags: audio

I have an [AT&T Model 1738 digital answering machine](https://att.vtp-media.com/media/p/document2/products/%7B876EE888-4197-4974-A073-96E90E30C2FA%7D/1738%20CIB%20.pdf) and I want to record the sound from one of the messages. The speaker in the answering machine is low quality, so I do not want to just play the message and use a microphone because that would result in a low-quality recording.

I would rather collect the audio information from some point before it gets amplified and sent to the speaker. What would be the necessary equipment and general procedure to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the speaker is the reason the sound is poor?
Presumably the message got onto the answering machine by somebody calling you on the phone. The quality is already pretty poor after transmission through the phone network.

Comment: I agree with @ThePhoton also if it is a digital machine, the sampling rate may be pretty poor to minimize the storage requirements.

Answer (score 2):

General procedure starts with a schematic. If you can't find one (likely) then you will have to 'reverse-engineer' it by tracing the wiring inside the device.

Necessary equipment equipment includes a screwdriver, continuity tester or multimeter, pencil and paper, and a good pair of eyes. Some basic electronics knowledge will also help.

Once you have a schematic you should be able to determine where the audio signal is produced and amplified, then you can try probing different points to find the best signal.

Or just take the signal directly from the speaker terminals - on the assumption that the electronic signal is relatively high quality and most of the degradation occurs inside the speaker itself. Even in this case a schematic is still useful, as it may help to determine what kind of interface is required.

Comment: I think finding the signal will be the easy part. How do I record the signal?

Comment: Use the signal as a line input to another device maybe...

Comment: "How do I record the signal?" - what equipment do you have have that can record audio signals?

Answer (score 1):

Before you start reverse-engineering your answering machine, you need to realize that the recorded sound is pretty poor quality to begin with.

The telephone network itself bandlimits signals sent over it to a band from 300 to 3400 Hz. This allows the early phone network to provide uniform service quality over the analog loop from the central office to the customer using reasonable electronics for the early 20th century. Today it limits the bandwidth needed to transmit millions of calls over  the digitized phone network.

This band doesn't even capture the fundamental of a typical speaker's voice --- the system relies on human perception to reconstruct the voice sound from the strongly filtered version of it.

Your answering machine will have been this in mind, so it will use only a fairly crude ADC (maybe 8 bits, maybe less), and a low sampling rate (perhaps 8 kSa/s) to reduce costs. It will also have recorded whatever noise was on the line when your caller left their message.

So even if you find the analog signal being sent to the speaker, and re-digitize it with an ADC, you might not get much better sound than you had before.

Answer (score 0):

They sometimes use Windbond recorder chips,  and low quality is reduced if signal is too low or high.

If you have an aux input that accepts 1V typ audio signals on a computer you can record it and playback by tapping into speaker wire pair.